# Single word request: a notable representative of a discipline

Tags: single-word-requests

Single word request: a notable representative of a discipline

e.g. Picasso and Braque - Cubism

Picasso and Braque were "important representatives" of Cubism

Is there a word to replace "important representatives"?

Comment: Picasso and Braque are widely regarded as having created/invented the genre of cubism, and therefore to describe them as "important representatives" is somewhat of an understatement. "Picasso and Braque were **the founders** of Cubism.

Comment: *Pioneers*. There was an exhibition entitled: *Braque and Picasso: Pioneering Cubism*

Comment: The _duplicate_ asks for a hypernym, admittedly, but all the obvious answers (epitome / paragon / paradigm / archetype ...) are given.

Comment: thanks. I think the example was misleading as Picasso and Braque are anchored to Cubism in a way that I do not wish to convey. I thought there may be a latin expression (for example) for the most notable contributors to a particular discipline (not necessarily the "founders")

Comment: "Picasso and Braque were Cubist masters"? "...masters of Cubism"?

Comment: For posterity, I would also like to suggest _**icon**_: *a person or thing regarded as a representative symbol or as worthy of veneration*. So:  _Picasso and Braque are* icons of Cubism._ *use present tense

Answer (score 2):

A representative of something can be notable or important in different ways, so the choice of the word will depend on the kind of importance that one has in mind. As has already been suggested in the comments, Picasso and Braque can be regarded as important representatives of cubism because they started that artistic movement; if that's what one has in mind, one will say that they were the **founders** of cubism. They are also important in that many of the people who don't know much about painting in general or cubism in particular, will know that they were cubists; if that's what one has in mind, one will say that they are the **best known** cubists.

What one may also have in mind, is that cubism is often defined by reference to their work: when one wants to teach somebody what cubism is, one will probably first point to their paintings. Whoever else may have been a cubist, they certainly were. Somebody who denied that Picasso was a cubist would be displaying a confusion about what the word *cubism* means. If that's the idea one wishes to express, one can say that they are **paradigmatic** cubists.

Comment: [*Use **paradigmatic** when you're talking about things that are **archetypal** or representative of some category and you want to sound impressive. You'll come across it if you study the subject of linguistics, where "paradigmatic analysis" is one way of analyzing a text, by examining patterns within it. The Greek word for "pattern," paradeigma, is the root of paradigmatic.*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/paradigmatic) I'm left with the general impression that supports my preference for the more common ***archetypal*** over ***paradigmatic*** for OP's context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, it is true that *archetypal* can also be used here; whether *paradigmatic* or *archetypal* is more pretentious (sounds more impressive) is a matter of taste. For some people, the term *archetypal* is strongly associated with Jungian psychology, where it is a technical term, and that may be a reason for avoiding it when one does not wish to invoke these associations. *Paradigm* on the other hand, invokes associations with Platonism, which are quite illuminating here. Incidentally, did you really intend most of your comment to be a link?

Comment: Yeah - sorry if my "extended link text" causes legibility issues on some displays. One thing I ***did*** find interesting was that when I tried comparing *was the **archetypal** model* with *was the **paradigmatic** model* on [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+the+archetypal+model%2Cwas+the+paradigmatic+model&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20the%20archetypal%20model%3B%2Cc0), there were no results for the latter. ***But*** when I removed the word ***was***, the two forms came out about equally common.

Comment: ...which lends support to the stuff cited in my earlier comment (implying that ***paradigmatic*** is more likely to be applied to a method / approach, whereas ***archetypal*** works better for ***actual instances*** of whatever is being referenced).

Answer (score 1):

People who are "important representatives" can be said to be

> **renowned**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> Known or talked about by many people; famous.
>   *The towering walls were covered with paintings of the world's most renowned artists.*

(from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/renowned))

> Picasso and Braque were renowned pioneers of Cubism.

The word [**pioneer**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pioneer) prompted by @TinfoilHat.